# Using Angular, how Can I add dynamically a component on click ? (Not only one)

Tags: angular, dynamic, components, directive

To learn Angular I'm coding a to-do list.
I've created a component task with a title (task name) and status (a boolean related to a checkbox input) parameters.

```
<div>
  <div>{{title}} <button>Edit</button></div>
  <input type="checkbox" value={{status}}>
</div>
```

I've also created a `ToDoList` component which contain a title(name of the to-do list, and a tab with a list of task name to generate multiple task component using a `*ngFor`.

```
<div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <app-task *ngFor="let title of list" [title]="title" status="true"></app-task>
  <button (click)="appTaskDirective">Add a task</button>
</div>
```

Now I want to add dynamically task components on click on the *"Add a task button"* while using the `appTaskDirective` but I just can't figure it out.

The angular [document example](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) can't help.

Here is my `appTaskDirective` file:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTaskDirective]'
})

export class TaskDirectiveDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(public viewContainer:ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54027187/9386929

Comment: this may help too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53191913/9386929

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5: Lazy-loading of component without routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50648142/angular-5-lazy-loading-of-component-without-routing)

Comment: I think your a bit confused about how attributes directives work. To accomplish your purpose you don't need a directive, but just a method that push another title inside the list array and that is called on button's click

Comment: I've created this stackblitz to show you how directives work. But @Yusuff answer, explains exactly what I meant in my last comment. P.S. your ToDoList component it's the app.component in my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abymzs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-task.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you can't pass a directive to the click event.
If you want to use the directive to listen to the click event you have to attach an hostlistener to the directive like this

**In directive**

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, OnInitHostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTaskDirective]'
})

export class TaskDirectiveDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(public viewContainer:ViewContainerRef) { }
    @HostListener('click') onClick() {
     // do something
    }
}
```

**In component**

```
<div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <app-task *ngFor="let title of list" [title]="title" status="true"></app-task>
  <button appTaskDirective>Add a task</button>
</div>
```

But I don't see why you need to do all these though. You can just listen to the event in the component and update the tasklist accordingly

**In component html**

```
<div>
 <h1>{{title}}</h1>
 <app-task *ngFor="let title of list" [title]="title" status="true"></app-task>
 <button (click)="addNewTask()">Add a task</button>
</div>
```

**In component ts**

```
addNewTask() {
   this.list.push('A new Task');
}
```

Hope this helps :)